# Can Citrix application able to access clients localhost

Tags: citrix

I have couple of questions related to working of citrix application. At first il explain the scenario...

1. Consider I have 2 application which is installed in Citrix server

   ```
   APP "A"  - Which is accessible to the clients through citrix connection(published)

   APP "B"  -  Which is installed in Citrix server(not published) and will act as a mediator for citrix app ("A") and clients local machine
   ```

Here is the scenario,

- In APP "A" we have link which will try to contact the clients local app and localhost through APP "B", means "B" will act as a mediator(for some validation and security purpose we are using this "B") for citrix application and clients local application. Means "A" will send request to "B" and "B" is the one responsible for contacting the clients local app, and in this case, if some thing goes wrong in "B", "B" has to show message box to the user.

Now my questions are:

1. As "B" is not published, Can user be able to see the APP "B"s message box???
2. If I want question 1 to done, wat ive to do?
3. If I refer "http://localhost //something" in APP "B", which IIS it will point to, "Clients local machines localhost" or "Citrix servers localhost".??
4. Can user be able to access any of the other application other than APP "A"??

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in Advance

Madhu M

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the application is published seamlessly, the user will not see any windows from other applications running in that terminal session. This is true unless the published application explicitly calls another app. For example, if I'm in IE and click a mailto link and Outlook is installed, it would launch and appear seamlessly to the user.
2. Does app "B" have a GUI or if it's just a process? If it's just a process, I would create a batch file that launches it in the background for each user.
3. Citrix server's localhost
4. Not exactly sure what your asking here.